# Making a JQuery ajax request conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to skip all this piece of code if some preconditions are not met, but I also want to move all the code between the parenthesis in a function. Is it allowed? I don't understand how this syntax works.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlAppend,
        data: JSON.stringify(xxx),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (canceled) {
                return;
            }
                //Long code
            }
        //Long code 2
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert('ppp');
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes you can.. did you even try ?

Comment: You want to skip the entire call to `$ajax`? Can't you just wrap that code in an `if` statement?

Comment: @Lix: yes, I don't want ajax to be called.

Comment: Why not: `if(condition) {$.ajax(...)}` ???

Comment: So just wrap it in a conditional expression.. I'm not sure I understand what the issue is here...

Comment: @pr1nc3: I tried but probably I wronged something then.. I would like to write it in a more elegant way like in a function..

Comment: @Revious - you would still have a conditional expression deciding whether to call the function or not...

Comment: @Lix: I'd prefer to move it into a function (since it's more clean). Is it possible?

Comment: @Revious - yes.. most certainly... But I still don't understand what the problem is... Are you asking how to write a function?

Comment: @Lix: how to mix the syntax to write a function and the syntax to call ajax.

Comment: The same way you "mix the syntax" of writing a function and writing any other statement.

Comment: This is quite elementary, which is why you are getting a lot of confused looks right now. Step 1: Write a function. Step 2: Write an `if` statement inside the function. Step 3: Copy and paste the `$.ajax` code into the `if` statement. Step 4: Call the function to test it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place your `$.ajax` call into a function, then wrap the call to the function in a conditional expression:

```
function makeRequest(){
  $.ajax( ... )
}

if ( some_condition ){
  makeRequest();
}
```

Keep in mind that you are using some variables inside the AJAX callback (namely the `canceled` variable). You'll have to make that variable available to the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
function doComplexStuff(){

} 

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlAppend,
        data: JSON.stringify(xxx),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: false,
        success: doComplexStuff,
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert('ppp');
        }
    });
```

The `doComplexStuff` will automatically receive all the params that the success function receives.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function runAjax(params){
    $.ajax({
        type: params["post"],
        url: params["url"],
        data: params["data"],
        contentType: params["content_type"],
        dataType: params["json"],
        processdata: params["process_bool"],
        success: function (result) {
            if (params["canceled"]) {
                return;
            }
                //Long code
            }
        //Long code 2
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert('ppp');
        }
    });
}

if(condition){
  var options = {
      //set options here
  };
  runAjax(options);
}
```

Comment: @Revious No problem, anytime

Comment: Still fighting against it.. I've some problems with the variables.

Comment: Let me know what you need help with. Its ok if you dont give me the green checkmark, just wanna make sure you have a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this sample:

```
function callAjax(condition) {
    if (condition) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlAppend,
            data: JSON.stringify(xxx),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processdata: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (canceled) {
                    return;
                }
                    //Long code
                }
            //Long code 2
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                alert('ppp');
            }
        });
    }
}

// Somewhere in your code
callAjax(condition);
```

Comment: If the **entire** function is dependent on a specific condition it would improve readability to have the condition wrapping the actual invocation of the function. You only `callAjax` *if* XYZ makes more sense than knowing `callAjax` sometimes gets executed and sometimes not - but is always called...